# Explore stored procedure and add one more parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am stuck here, and I lost somewhere in middle. So I will try to explain the situation.

I have a stored procedure which `INSERT`s data into a table, and it works perfectly.  Now I add one more variable and this variable is crucial.

I fetch data from Active Directory and store it to a file. From another side I have table in database which also contain some data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADProcTemp]
    @Username varchar(250),
    @DisplayName varchar(70),
    @isEnabled tinyint,
    @PassNevExp tinyint
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 PrezimeIme FROM [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD] WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   WHERE NetworkLogin = @Username)
    BEGIN
        IF(@isEnabled = 1)
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD](NetworkLogin, PrezimeIme, Status, PassNevExp)
            VALUES (@Username, @DisplayName, @isEnabled, @PassNevExp)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD]
        SET Status = @isEnabled         
        WHERE NetworkLogin = @Username 
          AND Status <> @isEnabled              
    END

    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS NumberOfRowsAffected
END
```

Now I add `if(@isEnabled = 1)` and right now I need to add logic if PassNevExp also. Something like these logic.

```
@isEnable  @PassNevExp      Result
------------------------------------
   0            0           Nothing
   0            1           INSERT
   1            0           INSERT
   1            1           INSERT
```

For me, this is a little bit complicated and I am stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to update the `Status` value conditionally:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD]
    SET Status = CASE
            WHEN @isEnable=0 AND @PassNevExp=0 THEN 'Nothing'
            WHEN @isEnable=0 AND @PassNevExp=1 THEN 'First Case'
            WHEN @isEnable=1 AND @PassNevExp=0 THEN 'Second Case'
            WHEN @isEnable=1 AND @PassNevExp=1 THEN 'Third Case'
        END
WHERE
    NetworkLogin = @Username 
    AND Status <> @isEnabled;
```